# Failing in adding reference to SOAP Service in C# console application

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to add reference to the service located on 'http://xt-adapt-ar.just.ee:81/ariport/?wsdl'.
But getting following error and I have no idea what to do. Usually adding a reference is quite straight forward, so I'm confused.

Following message is provided by VS 2012:

> The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
>
> - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
> - The 'documentation' element is not supported in this context.
>
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://xt-adapt-ar.just.ee:81/ariport/?wsdl'. The content type
>   text/xml; charset="UTF-8" of the response message does not match the
>   content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8).
>
> If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported
>   method is implemented properly.  The first 1024 bytes of the response
>   were:  '...'.
>
> If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the
>   solution and adding the service reference again.

All the ideas are useful so don't hesitate to share your knowledge or experience with similar issues!

P.S Project I'm building is Console Application also .NET framework is 4.0

Case closed.

Problem was with XSD files refered from WSDL. VisualStudi tool for adding service reference was not able to access all the XSD files. But it's ok because they don't have to response for GET request.

> So the workaround would be:
>
> - Download WSDL and all the XSD refered from WSDL
> - change URLs of XSD's in WSDL (schemaLocation urls)
> - also removing tags "documentation" from XSD's was required

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this an .asmx/.svc ... ?

Comment: The service is not written/made by me so I have no idea. It's just some SOAP service.

I hope i should be able to communicate with any SOAP services..?

Comment: Can you confirm that the .wsdl is actually working? I'm getting a connection timeout....

Comment: try to browse: http://xt-adapt-ar.just.ee:81/ariport/?wsdl

I'm getting the wsdl. it might be some location permission because it's a government service(but its public service so i think it should work)

At least I\m able to browse it with my Chrome